# Python Jedi Completion layout unusable

Tags: python, completion, auto-complete-mode

Today I decided to install emacs and give it a try. I followed some tutorials/examples/explanations and managed to install `Python Jedi` for getting suggestions while coding / code completion. It does that nicely, but there is one issue with it. The list with the completion suggestions is so wide, that the documentation strings don't have any space anymore and are squeezed into a single column. A screenshot will help to show what I am talking about: [screenshot](http://i.snag.gy/UQM6R.jpg)

Any ideas how I could fix this? (Keep in mind, I only installed emacs today and it's totally new to me.)

After solving the issue, my .emacs file contains these lines

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
(setq jedia:ac-max-width 0.5) ; This line solved the issue.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure max width by `ac-max-width`. Could you set its value, for example `0.5` as below ?

```
(setq ac-max-width 0.5)
```

I suppose this issue is not occurred in [company-jedi](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-company-jedi/)

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thank you. I guessed I have to add `(setq jedia:ac-max-width 0.5)` to make it jedi specific and that worked immediately :)